# c# wcf calling client callback from another client

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

I have wcf project with duplex contracts where i can invoke callback methods resident in clients app from the service.
I am wondering if i have a way to invoke clients callback methods from another client directly .
I am thinking of getting the callback variable from the service and invoke the callback method using it.
is this approach working, or any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you're trying to broadcast: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service
Or under which other circumstances would you like to do that?

Comment: thanks for your support , i am already can brodacast, but what i am asking about is client to client method invloking.

Answer (score 0):

**.Net Remoting** may be helpful for you,check this code project link

[.NET Remoting with an easy example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example)

Comment: As i understand .NET remoting is old fashioned and obsolete , WCF is the modern approach.